# How to align <a> tag to the same height as <v-btn> in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The *Create account* link and the *Continue* button are not on the same height. How do I fix this?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
    <v-col cols="6">
      <a
        class=""
        style="vertical-align: bottom white-space: nowrap"
        @click="redirectSignup()"
        >Create account</a
      >
    </v-col>
    <v-col class="d-flex justify-end" cols="6">
      <v-btn
        depressed
        color="primary"
        @click="
          valid ? checkEmailAndContinue({ email: emailField }) : $refs.email.validate()
        "
        >Continue</v-btn
      ></v-col
    >
```

Comment: `vertical-align: bottom white-space: nowrap` is an invalid ruleset. There **must be**  a semi-colon separating rules in a ruleset.

Comment: Thank you but this did not fix the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making the column and the  tag a flex and aligning the  tag to the center like that:

```
    <v-col class="d-flex" shrink>
      <a class="d-flex align-center" style="white-space: nowrap" @click="redirectForgot()"
        >Forgot password?</a>
    </v-col>
```